# How to run an Instrumental Variable Regression for heterogenous treatment effects

Tags: stata, instrumental-variables, treatment-effect

I am working with a panel data with two periods (dummy variable time equals 1 for post-intervention data) and two groups (dummy variable intervention equals 1 for the group which received the treatment). As such, I ran the following on STATA:

xi: ivregress 2sls outcomevar intervention time (instrument=did)

where did=intervention*time.

It works perfectly well. However, I was wondering how I could assess the effect of female vs male respondents for example. Should I use a triple-difference to do so? Or run the regression seperately for female and male respondents?

Thank you

Comment: Cross-posted on [Statalist](https://www.statalist.org/forums/forum/general-stata-discussion/general/1421515-heterogenous-treatment-effect-with-difference-in-differences).

Comment: Hi Dimitriy, it's a different question - on statalist, I am asking about DID heterogeneous effects, whereas here, I am using about IV regression